# Width of svg polygon tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Given this svg polygon:

```
<polygon class="range_arrow"
     id="arrow"
     points="0,0 5,5 0,10 -5,5"
     data-width="10"/>
```

I can get the width if I've entered it manually.

```
$('#arrow').data("width");
```

However `$('#arrow').width();` returns `0` and `$('#arrow').attr("width");` returns `undefined`

Is it possible to get the correct width for a polygon tag?

Comment: I cant see an error... bud you should using .prop() instead of .attr()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the bounding box and that will give you the width e.g.

```
$('#arrow')[0].getBBox().width;
```